# Will Kexy (calligra office suite) work in elementary?

Tags: apps

Do such desktop database applications as kexy (calligra office suite) work in elementary? In application documentation There's no elementary mentioned as a supporting OS

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that elementary is a ubuntu based distribution, according to: 
https://userbase.kde.org/Calligra/Download#Ubuntu

The current calligra release is unstable on it. 
Also it would require a lot of KDE environment dependencies. 
perhaps Create a Virtual machine of Elementary and then follow the above install guide and see if it breaks before you try it on your live environment? 
:)

Comment: thanx, perhaps it worth starting up with things like mint (want to get rid of my slowing down win7), appreciate it